# Tengo esta web que estoy maquetando la cual no hace scroll ¿Alguien puede decirme el por qué?

Tags: html, css

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Lobster";
    max-width: 1920px;
}
body{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
}


#título{
   text-align: center;
    font-size: 340%;
    background: white;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 220px;
    line-height: 180px;
}
#icono{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.flexslider{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
.slides{
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
}
.caption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    align-self: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li{
    padding-left: 15px;
   
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.flex-control-nav li a{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    
}
#img1{
    width: 230px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img2{
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img3{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img4{
    width: 200px;
    height: 330px;
}
#img5{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
#head1{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  font-size:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
  background: white;
  width: 1440px;
  }
  #text1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 1440px;
  }
  #cuadro1{
      background: white;
      width: 1920px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-right: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="efects.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="✅En Todo Smartphone podrás encontrar las ofertas que necesitabas para comprar tu smartphone ideal al mejor precio."  >
    <meta name="author" content="Juan Antonio de la Cruz WEB DEVELOPER">
    <title>⭐TodoSmartphone⭐ Encuentra Tu Smartphone Ideal Con La Mejore Oferta |PÁGINA PRINCIPAL|</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="título"><h1>TodoSmartphone</h1></header>
    <div id="icono">
        <span>&#9776</span>
   <div id="fondo"></div>
   
   <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

        <li>
            <img id="img1" src="./img/iphone11.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
               <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup> 
            </section>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img id="img2" src="./img/s20fe.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img id="img3" src="./img/mi-10.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img id="img4" src="./img/opnord.png" alt="">
        <section class="caption">
        <hgroup><h2>ghjhg</h2></hgroup>
        </section>
       </li>
        
        <li>
            <img id="img5" src="./img/realme7pro.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hgroup><h2 id="head1">ENCUENTRA EL SMARTPHONE QUE NECESITAS</h2></hgroup>
<p id="text1">En TodoSmartphone, podrás encontrar las mejores ofertas de los mejores móviles del momento.
    Continua bajando para encontrar los más recomendados, divididos en secciones para facilitar tu decisión, 
    utiliza el icono de la esquina superior para filtrar por tus marcas favoritas o usa nuestro buscador para encontrar un modelo concreto y compra a través de Amazon con total seguridad.
</p>
<div id="cuadro1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Las librerías flexslider y jquery están instaladas y tengo algo de código javascript, pero lo he sacado porque no me dejaba añadir la librería flexslider, de todas formas esto no afecta al código, sigue ocurriendo lo mismo, la web se corta y no deja hacer scroll. Si alguien puede decirme que ha ocurrido? Es la primera vez que me pasa esto y he probado varias formas como añadir overflow=auto, pero nada. La cosa es que al hacer ctrl+la rueda del ratón el fondo azul y morado empieza ha repertirse una y otra vez, hay alguna forma de arreglarlo o debería quitar ese fondo del body y solo añadirlo para los backgrounds de algunos objetos.

pd: La web está recién empezada y hay que añadir mucho más y corregir cosas como que el blanco del título 1 se sale fuera de la web y hay que dejarle un espacio por los márgenes.

Comment: Ahora imagínate una cosa, que no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta. Yo estoy de vacaciones en españa, pero mi dispositivo solo tiene idioma japonés instalado... qué pasará cuando intente abrir tu página web y exista esta clase `#título`? Porque la `í` no es un caracter válido en muchos idiomas! Te recomiendo que ***NUNCA*** utilices acentos/eñes cuando estás programando. Obviamente me refiero a no ponerlos en nombres de variables, clases o métodos, no en el *texto*!

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un error de sintaxis, te falta cerrar un div

```
<div id="icono"> <!-- te falta un </div> aqui o... -->
  <span>&#9776</span>
<div id="fondo"></div> <!-- o aqui, dependiendo de como tienes armado tu contenedor... -->
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: "Lobster";
    max-width: 1920px;
}
body{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( right, #49a09d, #5f2c82);
}


#título{
   text-align: center;
    font-size: 340%;
    background: white;
    width: 1920px;
    height: 220px;
    line-height: 180px;
}
#icono{
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 35px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 50px;
    width: 50px;
}
.flexslider{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}
.slides{
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
}
.caption{
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
}
.flex-control-nav.flex-control-paging{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
    align-self: center;
}
.flex-control-nav li{
    padding-left: 15px;
   
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.flex-control-nav li a{
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: black;
    color: black;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    
}
#img1{
    width: 230px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img2{
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img3{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
#img4{
    width: 200px;
    height: 330px;
}
#img5{
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
}
#head1{
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 190px;
    margin-right: 50px;
  font-size:100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
  background: white;
  width: 1440px;
  }
  #text1{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  width: 1440px;
  }
  #cuadro1{
      background: white;
      width: 1920px;
      height: 200px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      margin-right: 50px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
    <script src="efects.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="✅En Todo Smartphone podrás encontrar las ofertas que necesitabas para comprar tu smartphone ideal al mejor precio."  >
    <meta name="author" content="Juan Antonio de la Cruz WEB DEVELOPER">
    <title>⭐TodoSmartphone⭐ Encuentra Tu Smartphone Ideal Con La Mejore Oferta |PÁGINA PRINCIPAL|</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="título"><h1>TodoSmartphone</h1></header>
    <div id="icono"> 
        <span>&#9776</span>
   <div id="fondo"></div></div>
   
   <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">

        <li>
            <img id="img1" src="./img/iphone11.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
               <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup> 
            </section>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img id="img2" src="./img/s20fe.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img id="img3" src="./img/mi-10.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>
        <li>
        <img id="img4" src="./img/opnord.png" alt="">
        <section class="caption">
        <hgroup><h2>ghjhg</h2></hgroup>
        </section>
       </li>
        
        <li>
            <img id="img5" src="./img/realme7pro.png" alt="">
            <section class="caption">
                <hgroup><h2>Lorem slider #1</h2></hgroup>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<hgroup><h2 id="head1">ENCUENTRA EL SMARTPHONE QUE NECESITAS</h2></hgroup>
<p id="text1">En TodoSmartphone, podrás encontrar las mejores ofertas de los mejores móviles del momento.
    Continua bajando para encontrar los más recomendados, divididos en secciones para facilitar tu decisión, 
    utiliza el icono de la esquina superior para filtrar por tus marcas favoritas o usa nuestro buscador para encontrar un modelo concreto y compra a través de Amazon con total seguridad.
</p>
<div id="cuadro1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buah muchas gracias, valiente tontería jjaaajj